# Nginx proxy_pass to a password protected upstream

Tags: proxy, nginx, basic-authentication

I want to pass a request to an upstream server.  The original url is not password protected but the upstream server is.  I need to inject a Basic auth username/password into the request but get errors when doing:

```
upstream supportbackend {
       server username:password@support.yadayada.com;
}
```

and

```
upstream supportbackend {
       server support.yadayada.com;
}

location /deleteuser {
    proxy_pass http://username:password@supportbackend;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to add `proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic ....";` where the `....` is base64 of `user:pass`.

Comment: It should actually be: `proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic ....";` In the answer, the `Basic` bit was excluded.